# Separating Gtk.Grid into two rows

Tags: gtk, vala

I want to have two "rows" inside of my `Gtk.Grid`.

Each row will have its elements. The top row will have a couple of labels attached next to each other, while the bottom row is going to have two buttons next to each other. Elements in both rows should be centered on the screen.

I don't have any previous experience in working with Vala, but I thought I can do it like this:

```
//declaration of the grid
var layout = new Grid ();
layout.orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL;

//declaration of labels
...

//attaching of labels
layout.attach (label1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
layout.attach_next_to (label2, label1, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1);
layout.attach_next_to (label3, label2, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1);
layout.attach_next_to (label4, label3, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1);
layout.attach_next_to (label5, label4, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1);

//declaration of buttons
...

layout.attach (startBtn, 0, 0, 1, 1);
layout.attach_next_to (stopBtn, startBtn, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1);
```

But looks like it doesn't work that way. I tried to find some examples, but they all seem to have bunch of code next to it so now I'm exhausted and I still can't find the way to work this out.

**EDIT**: The result I'm getting is shown below.

[image]

Comment: What happens with the code that you posted? You seem to almost have it, but I'm not entirely sure what you're missing.

Comment: @andlabs I added the screenshot displaying the result I'm getting.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The `0, 0` arguments to `attach()` are the cell to attach to. You're replacing controls. (You should probably have a warning on stderr; if not...) See [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkGrid.html#gtk-grid-attach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very good article about this topic: http://www.abenga.com/post/2014/11/10/layout-widgets/

As andlabs pointed out, I would use 
`public void attach (Widget child, int left, int top, int width = 1, int height = 1)`
http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Grid.attach1

```
layout.attach (label1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
layout.attach (label2, 1, 0, 1, 1);
layout.attach (label3, 0, 1, 1, 1);
layout.attach (label4, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Fore something like this

```
-------------------
| label1 | label2 |
-------------------
| label3 | label4 |
-------------------
```